# Clicking caret icon inside bootstrap link does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v3.3.7 and jQuery v1.12.4, I am creating a component which activates a HTML popover.

Please see the code below.

Clicking the button activates the popover. However clicking the caret icon within the button does not do anything. Any idea why and how to resolve this?

[Click here for the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nah44v3b/).

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default po" data-poc="#html1">Test 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
<a role="button" class="btn btn-default po" data-poc="#html2">Test 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
<div id="html1" class="hide">
  <strong>This</strong> is a test!
</div>
<div id="html2" class="hide">
  <strong>This</strong> is another test!
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
<a id="po1" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/x1gcnx23/1/)

Comment: Perfect, this works best for me. Thank you. See https://jsfiddle.net/davidenco/nah44v3b/1/